# Convert bitmap image to byte array and then send it to the main thread

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask

I am trying to convert bitmap image to byte array after the result from `onpostexecute` in the `async task class`. The results are correctly set in the `onpostexecute`, but when it gets to the part of convertion( converting from bitmap to byte array) then it throws an error.

This is the on create method

```
 ...
public byte[]  ImageArray;
public  Bitmap ImageBitmap;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //This instantiate the async class
    DownloadImageTask asyncTask =new  DownloadImageTask(new AsyncResponse() {

        @Override
        public void processFinish(Bitmap output) {

            ImageBitmap = output;
        }
    });

    asyncTask.execute(imageurl);


    //I want to be able to get the ImageArray on the main thread after the async task execution
        ....
}



/**
 * This sub class downloads the attached  image
 * file to be viewed on the page.
 */
private class  DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    public AsyncResponse delegate=null;


    public DownloadImageTask(AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
        delegate = asyncResponse; //Assigning call back interfacethrough constructor
    }


    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        delegate.processFinish(result);


        //This converts the bitmap to an byte array 
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
        ImageArray = stream.toByteArray();
    }
}


//This creates an interface for the results from the async task
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(Bitmap output);
}
```

Please is it possible to convert the bitmap image to byte array in the `onPostExecute` and get the `ImageArray` on the main thread? If yes, please how can i do it, because what i did craches the app. Thanks for helping

**UPDATE**

Please the error in the logcat has been added to the question

> 8334-8334/com.myaapp.onookow E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.myaapp.onookow.onokows$DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(onokows.java:342)
>               at com.myaapp.onookow.onokows$DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(onokows.java:311)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method).

**STRANGE UPDATE**

After testing the app on a device which has API > 11, every thing works. But testing on a device which has API < 11, every thing started to work but within some few seconds the app freezes with this pop image, check below

[image]

Comment: And you figured that posting the error it throws is irrelevant, how?

Comment: @StefandeBruijn it gives a  `java.lang.NullPointerException` error in the log cat

Comment: psot your logcat error..

Comment: But where posting your logcat stacktrace might be useful..

Comment: @StefandeBruijn  Please I have added the logcat error to the question, Sorry for the delay

Comment: @RajSharma please check my update, sorry for the delay, Thanks for helping

Comment: onPostExecute() already runs in the main thread.

Comment: Sure, but the `onPostExecute()` never get successful with  bitmap conversion in there, so I was even thinking it is not correct to convert the bitmap into byte within the `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Please check the new strange update.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
delegate.processFinish(result);
```

Should be put after:

```
//This converts the bitmap to an byte array 
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
ImageArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Otherwise ImageArray == null in processFinish()

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the imageArray is not null however putting the `delegate.processFinish(result)` after the conversion doesnt work

Comment: Please Check the new strange update from the question

Answer (score 0):

in the below function-

```
  protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

    delegate.processFinish(result);


    //This converts the bitmap to an byte array 
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
    ImageArray = stream.toByteArray();
}
```

}

the parameter is a result which is of type Bitmap.
But you are not using result anywhere in the code. I am wondering how conversion is done from bitmap to bytearray?.
I think you are not setting your result bitmap to any of the stream.

Comment: sorry the ImageBitmap is the bitmap result so like  `result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);`